# Как запретить показ конкретных XHR запросов в консоли хрома

Tags: отладка, chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Существует ли способ запретить вывод в google-chrome dev-tools во вкладке network ненужные XHR запросы?

Сейчас во вкладке network выводятся все соединения включая все расширения google-chrome что мешает отладке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы видеть только запросы-ответы веб приложения. Не хотелось бы отключать ради этого все расширения так как периодически ими пользуюсь.

Comment: Фильтрация чем не устроила?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Фильтрацией и пользуюсь. Но не всегда точно знаешь название запроса. Или запросов несколько. 
Думал есть способ отключить отображение запросов расширений отдельно.

Comment: @r.u.f.f можно сделать фильтр по названию файла

Comment: Такой возможности нет. Однако в поле filter вы можете использовать регулярные выражения и [дополнительные параметры поиска](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#filter-by-property).

Comment: @Deliaz да, это по большей части решило мою проблему. Спасибо!